# What is the difference between api-package, invoker-package and package-name options in OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

OpenAPI Generator docs contains a list of all available options which are relevant for any OpenAPI Generator tooling (CLI, Maven/Gradle plugins etc.). There are a couple of options which are confusing to me and I don't understand the difference: **--api-package**, **--invoker-package** and **--package-name**. Here are their descriptions taken from the [User Manual](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage#generate):

> --api-package <api package>: package for generated api classes

> --invoker-package <invoker package>: root package for generated code

> --package-name <package name>: package for generated classes (where supported)

Can someone explain the difference between these 3 options?

Note: Not sure if this is any relevant, but I am asking this question in the context of Java stack with Gradle OpenAPI Generator plugin.

Comment: Try to specify different packages names for these options, and generate them. You will see the difference in the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

From the context of Java, these are packages. For example, the `spring` generator defines the following defaults:

- apiPackage -- `org.openapitools.api`
- invokerPackage -- `org.openapitools.api`

The `spring` generator does not have any references for `packageName`, so it is not supported.
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java#L139...L141

So, those options merely control how [Java packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) are generated.